# each cell of table view displays the same value multiple times

Tags: ios, uitableview

Following is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }



    self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {

        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {

        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

    }




    self.productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
    self.productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[indexPath.row];
    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];


    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountTextLabel];

    //    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
    //    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    //    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    //[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that, when I say amountArray[indexPath.row], it should display two unique values but it displays the same value multiple times. I have even looped
around table view to check if it has two values and it does but while displaying it prints same value is displayed multiple times.

Comment: U didn't add the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Just put the cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

Comment: Create productAmountLabel locally in that method. Don't make it global.

Comment: @SRNayak can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when you perform `addSubview` on a `UITableViewCell` is that it will get added multiple times when `cellForRow:atIndexPath` is invoked.

You can solve the problem in two ways:

1. Have a custom cell with the custom labels already added on init. In this case, you won't have to do `addSubview` in `cellForRow`.
2. Remove all subviews in `cellForRow` before adding any subviews, like so:

   ```
    for (UIView *sView in cell.contentView.subviews) {

         [sView removeFromSuperview];
    }
   ```

As a quickfix, approach 2 will work, but approach 1 is better, since you avoid unnecessary adding/removing of subviews.

**EDIT**

On reconsideration, there is a third way. Initialize your labels earlier and add the labels as subviews within the `(cell == nil)` block:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];
    self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: self.productAmountLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: self.productAmountTextLabel];
    }

// remaining code, but do not call `addSubview` after this point

}
```

Comment: Which approach did you try?

Comment: i have tried both of those approach yet the same problem prevails bro

Answer (score 1):

Do like below code :

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *indentifier = @"indentifier";

   // Here I am creating cell in XIB -----------

   Team_TableViewCell *Cell = (Team_TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indentifier];
   if (Cell == nil)
   {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Team_TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
       Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }

   // My required lable--------
   Cell.titleLbl.text = reportees.name;
   Cell.pointEarnedLbl.text = reportees.points;
   Cell.titleLbl.textColor=APP_HOME_TABLE_HEADER_COLOR;
   [Cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
   [Cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

   return Cell;
}
```

Note : Set the Indentifier in Tableview also if u r creating in XIB..

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: U create all labels in locally ?

Comment: can u send me the code on this mail               imindpixel@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier like this

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
static NSString *cellId=@"reuseid";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil)

{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}

self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 20)];
self.productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,25, 100, 20)];


self.productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
self.productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];


self.productAmountTextLabel.text = [amountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

[cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountTextLabel];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: `'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier  - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: You can register in viewdidload method like this    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"reuseid"];